Why am I unable to authenticate Jira API for a Jira Cloud instance?
I am currently writing a Python script. I have previously successfully authenticated a Jira Cloud instance using the Jira library, using the below:
jcloud = JIRA(server="https://www.jcloudurl.atlassian.net, basic_auth=('user', 'token'))
Which ran successfully/threw no errors.
I have checked the following as well:

I have all the necessary project and administrative permissions required to interact with the project I am trying to create a new issue in.
The Jira Cloud instance is version updated.

When I try to print the projects that are on this Jira Cloud, I get an empty list:
print(jcloud.projects())
[]

When I tried to create an issue in the project, I get the following error:
JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 404 url: https://jcloudurl.atlassian.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/project/TEST

                text: No project could be found with key 'TEST'.

There is also a line in the more detailed error that says 'X-Seraph-Loginreason': 'AUTHENTICATED_FAILED'.
I am curious as to why my previous attempt, where I have changed nothing in the code, was successful and why it has failed now. I have searched high and low and cannot find any answers outside of project permissions and making sure the Cloud Jira URL is not the REST API URL. Any leads on this would be appreciated.
